# Wordpress, Custom Taxonomies Broken Every Install

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I just created my first proper theme and I'm having trouble working out the last bug, I have a custom 'portfolio' post type with its own custom taxonomy (portfolio-category). However, every/any time I install the theme on a different install of wordpress (all latest 3.5) the taxonomie is broken, does not display where it is supposed to. This is after adding new 'portfolio categories' and saving.

Pastebin of my taxonomy code from functions.php and the code I call it in (for an isotope filter).

If anyone could help me I'll love them forever <3

Thanks!

Sorry, forgot pastebin link http://pastebin.com/eVqndBZP

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the pastebin link but by past experience you probably just need to go to permalinks and press save.

Also see http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules

Comment: I did try saving the permalinks but no luck, here is the pastebin I forgot (sorry) http://pastebin.com/eVqndBZP

Comment: also, get_terms does not display empty categories

Comment: None of the category's are empty. Get terms was used to prevent empty cat's being displayed.

Comment: do you have DEBUG on, try to print_r the array and try using taxonomy_exists inside the template just in case

Comment: It might be worth noting that I "fixed" this problem before by renaming the taxonomy and then re-adding the category's, however after copying the "fixed" files to a new installation the problem happened again.